# What are the easy ways to search on windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I am looking for the easiest ways to search for

1. An App
2. A File
3. A Folder
4. A Store
   .... and soon

Still I need to update this question with some more search types.

Comment: So do you want "Best" or "Easiest"? ;)  What have you tried already?  Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Find...

**Applications**

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and start typing.

**File and folders**

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and start typing.

**Windows Store Applications**

Go to the Windows 8 Store, press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> or touch swipe from the right edge to open charms, then use the Search charm to search for applications, after pressing either the hotkey or the mouse / touch approach you can start typing.

Answer (score 1):

App: Just start typing in Modern UI screen (<kbd>Windows</kbd> key gets you there)

Files/Folders: <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and start typing

Comment: And a +1 for you for having a prettier answer.

Answer (score 1):

Openning the Command Line and typing `DIR /a /s filename`, assuming you know the exact file name